# Loading flash in vb.net webbrowser

Tags: vb.net, flash

I am currently developing a web browser in VB.net. I have already designed the forms and tested by browsing to Facebook or Google. But when I try to go to YouTube to play a video, the video control appears black and I cannot play the video.

The code is the following

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_Navigating(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.Navigating
    ProgressBar1.Visible = True
    With ProgressBar1
        .Minimum = 0
        .Maximum = 50
        .Step = 5
    End With
    For index As Integer = 0 To 50 Step 5
        ProgressBar1.Value = index
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(35)
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

I have been searching for a way to enable the web browser to play Flash videos but I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine and works perfectly on my laptop.

I would suspect that your installation of adobe flash player is the culprit.

Try to uninstall it and then re-install it.

[image: Preview of your code working with NO changes to code]

Comment: Alright i will check the installation of my flash player and i will come back Thanks